# How do I make my buttons respond to multiple touches programatically?

Tags: methods, colors, uibutton, touch

I have created several UIButton programmatically using:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

button.frame = CGRectMake(realX, realY, 64, 64);

[button setTitle: str forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.backgroundColor = greyButtonColor;
```

I want the buttons to cycle through colors depending on how many times they have been touched. Ex. Grey > Green > Blue > back to Grey. So how do I go about doing this using code? The code above is from a method I created to make my buttons. Should the code to teach it to behave based on the amount of touches go inside that method, or in a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact code but I think I can tell you how to solve the problem.

1. Register a click event for each button and assign a switchColor(buttonId) method
2. You need a currentStateButtonId variable for each button to save the state of the button

   - the initial value is 0 = gray
   - inside the method you check

     - if (currentStateButtonId == 0)
       -> currentStateButtonId = 1
       -> buttonId color = blue
     - else
       -> currentStateButtonId = 0
       -> buttonId color = gray